# How to estimate parameters of a hierarchical model?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, multilevel-analysis, expectation-maximization, frequentist

I have the following hierarchical model,

[image]

where $t$ stands for time and $y_t, x_{1t}, x_{2t}, \dots, z_{1t}, z_{2t}, \dots$ are known. I want to estimate the parameters of the model using a frequentist approach, not a Bayesian approach. Using Maximum Likelihood estimation seems appropriate to me. So, I was thinking of using an EM-algorithm. However, I am not sure if this is the best way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am going to state this in words, and if I am off, please correct me. You have a repeatedly measured outcome y_t, that you want to predict from x_1 and x_2. Additionally, you want to allow the effect of x_1 to vary across units (?) and you want to predict each unit's slope of x_1 using z_1 and z_2?

Comment: That is indeed what I want to do!

Comment: Do you want to write your own implementation of the EM algorithm or use existing tools designed for modeling this type of data?

Comment: I am trying to write my own EM algorithm in R. I came across the so called Monte Carlo EM algorithm, so that is what I am trying right now. Where the \beta_{1,t} are estimated with a Metropolis Algorithm and I estimate the remaining parameters.

Comment: Interesting! Good luck. It would be awesome if you posted the code and results when you get it working.